# Is it possible to remove variable repetition here?

Tags: php, object-oriented, strings

```
/**
    * Class stringHelperK
    * Helper Class to deal with small string manipulations.
*/
class stringHelperK {

    public function normalizeStringK($string) {
        return $this->removeAccents(
            $this->replaceSpacesWithSlashes($string)
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param $string
     * @return string
     */
    public function removeAccents($string){
        return strtr($string,'àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ','aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');
    }

    /**
     * @param $string
     * @return string
     */
    public function replaceSpacesWithSlashes($string) {
        return strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-",$string));
    }
}
```

I have several questions regarding this code:

1. `$string` is used across all class methods. Should it be a property?  If so, how can I transform this accordingly? I mean, I see `$string` everywhere and it feels isn't correct.

Is it, something like this, better:

```
/**
    * Class stringHelperK
    * Helper Class to deal with small string manipulations.
*/
class stringHelperK {

    public $string;

    public function normalizeStringK($string) {
        return $this->removeAccents(
            $this->replaceSpacesWithSlashes($this->string)
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param $string
     * @return string
     */
    public function removeAccents($string){
        return strtr($this->string,'àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ','aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');
    }

    /**
     * @param $string
     * @return string
     */
    public function replaceSpacesWithSlashes($string) {
        return strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-",$his->string));
    }
}
```

Or should it be, `private $_string`, and we should use `getters` and `setters`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This class looks like a utility class, and you could use static functions: you then wouldn't need to instantiate it:

```
class StringHelperK {

    public static function normalizeStringK($string) {
        return static::removeAccents(
            static::replaceSpacesWithSlashes($string)
        );
    }

    public static function removeAccents($string){
        return strtr($string,'àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ','aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');
    }

    public static function replaceSpacesWithSlashes($string) {
        return strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-",$string));
    }
}
```

To normalize a string, you would then do: `StringHelperK::normalizeStringK("blabla")`.

And no, $string should definitely not be a property, and I see nothing wrong with passing is as an argument to each function.

Comment: but I've been told, that, if we call an attribute on ALL methods, or almost ALL methods on a given class, it would be wise to pass it as a class property. Is this incorrect?

Comment: In this case it is because strings are immutable. If you were passing an object to all function and you were modifying the state of the object, then yes, by all means, use a property instead of an argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I've understand and learned from it. Again. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you might as well drop the class and just use functions. Don't use static methods, it's pointless.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I think a utility class is a nice approach, if not nothing more, as a way to organize the code under this OOP approach I'm taking in consideration. But I see your point, it would be quicker to just call a function and do the job. But where, should I place that bunch of functions? That's my doubt.

Comment: A Utility class is a *horrible* approach. What's in a Utility "Well, anything that's not found in any of the other classes!". Utilities turn to God objects very quickly. If you'd like I can elaborate more in chat.

Comment: I'm aware of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340032/utility-classes-are-evil :), and as stated there, there not evil `de per se`. But, Madara, my main doubt remains: where should we place those functions? I mean, we sure will use them cross project, and cross different moments of a given application development...

Comment: What's wrong with normal functions? That's what namespaces are for, after all.

Comment: I will have a look at namespaces since I heard them so often and, again, I'm aware that we should avoid the utility functions the most we can.

Answer (score 2):

1. `$string` should only be a property if it's *shared* between all the methods. You should ask yourself **Does it makes sense for this object to *remember* `$string`?**
2. Passing `$string` around is perfectly fine. If your function needs a string to do work, it should ask for it in the signature.